# Adobe Acrobat cannot extract embedded font FiraMath

Tags: pdf, fontspec, unicode-math, embedding, acrobat

When I create a pdf using Fira Math Regular as the math font I get the error

> Cannot extract embedded font 'SBTYLT+FiraMathRegular'. Some characters may not display or print correctly
> In my example provided below the left bracket is not being displayed in adobe acrobat while it is displayed in the texstudio preview.
> My tex file:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\begin{document}    
\(\{\}\)
\end{document}
```

Software used to create the output:

- MikTeX with lualatex `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 20.12) (format=lualatex 2021.1.12`
- FiraMath version 0.3.3 from MikTeX
- Adobe Acrobat Reader DC version 20.013.20074
- TeXStudio 3.0.4

How to correct the embedding of the Fira Math font in the pdf file so it can be correctly display in the Adobe Acrobat Reader?
I provided an example output from TeXstudio and Acrobat Reader.
[image: Left bracket is missing in Acrobat Reader]
[image: Left bracket is correctly displayed in TeXstudio]

Comment: seems to be a problem with the fira math version, I copied the version from texlive and then it worked. my miktex has version 0.3.3, and texlive and ctan 0.3.4., make a bug report for miktex, it should update the font.

Comment: This is a known `firamath` problem, see https://github.com/firamath/firamath/issues/53. And it has been resolved in `firamath` 0.3.4.

Comment: Overwriting the version provided by miktex like @UlrikeFischer described worked. I am not sure why Latex was not picking up Fira Math from my system fonts, which already was the version 0.3.4. Is there some internal priority given to fonts from the miktex directory?