# Adobe Reader cannot extract embedded font New Computer Modern

Tags: pdf, fontspec, embedding, acrobat, newcomputermodern

When I create a PDF using the `newcomputermodern` font and try to open it in Adobe Acrobat Reader DC, I get following error message, and some characters will not be displayed:

> Cannot extract embedded font 'RDUBLY+NewCM10-Book'. Some characters may not display or print correctly.

The error persists whether I am compiling with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, loading the `newcomputermodern` package or setting it as `mainfont` with `fontspec`; only the letters before '+NEWCM10-Book' change with some settings. In Adobe forums, some people raise similar issues related to an update from 2019, which seem to be resolved by now; and [a similar problem with the FiraMath font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/580996/adobe-acrobat-cannot-extract-embedded-font-firamath) was fixed by updating the font package.

However, even after updating to the newest version (3.01) of `newcomputermodern` in TeX Live and the current release of Adobe ARDC (2021.001.20135), the problem persists. TeX Studio's internal viewer and other programs (Drawboard PDF, Chrome, Edge) display the file without any issues.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage{newcomputermodern}
\usepackage{blindtext,microtype}

\begin{document}
    \section{A Section with \scshape small capitals} % to check whether the font is displayed properly
    {New \textsc{cm} has neat \bfseries bold \scshape small caps}. % so I'd like to keep using the font
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to properly embed the font, or is this an issue on Adobe's side only?

I am thankful for any help or suggestions!

---

### Edit

The problem seems to be limited to the `Book` weight of the font. Loading the font with `\usepackage[regular]{newcomputermodern}` changes the default weight to the (slightly lighter) `Regular` weight, which seems to be embedded in a way Adobe deems acceptable.

Comment: Welcome to the site! In your `.log` file, are you using the new version of the font you downloaded, or is the engine finding an older one in some other directory instead?

Comment: Oh, there is one line reading `/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newcomputermodern/newcomputermodern.sty
Package: newcomputermodern v2.33 NewCM fonts by Antonis Tsolomitis`

So it seems to be the old version...
How do I update this properly? I had updated via the TL Manager (and did a `texhash` just in case), but apparently that's not enough.

Comment: Option 1: as root/administrator/the account that owns your TeX install, run `tlmgr update --self newcomputermodern`.

Comment: Option 2: put the newer version of the fonts (or symbolic links to them) in your `TEXMFLOCAL` directory. You can find that with `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL`.

Comment: Option 3: Use the `Path=` option when loading the font. This will prevent your document from compiling on another box, though.

Comment: I did some digging and it seems I had the 3.01 installed all along. The `.log` still says v.2.33, but so does the `.sty` on CTAN. However, I narrowed the problem down and found a "solution" that makes my file at least readable for now and edited the question.

Comment: I unfortunately do not have a copy of that reader to test.

Comment: I can confirm the problem, you should notify the author of the font.

Comment: I know the problem exists with Acrobat. However, it does not produce any informative error and no other program has any problem with the font. Even GS converts to PS without errors. So I do not know currently what to fix. If Fira solved the problem, I will try to talk to the developers of Fira. Shekura what is your solution?

Comment: OK, some say that FontForge CounterMasks are the problem of Acrobat. I will write to FontForge lists. From Fira they just removed them to fix the issue with Acrobat.

Comment: Sorry, I did not have a solution for the Book weight; the "solution" I mentioned before was referring to using the Regular weight instead.

Comment: OK, the problem seems to be solved in my sources. The issue was with the CounterMasks for the letter m. I will re-generate the otfs and re-upload to CTAN. It will take me a day or so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 3.02 has been uploaded to CTAN, and it solves the Acrobat problem. It should be in the mirrors after about a day, so you need to update to this version if you are using Acrobat.

Comment: Thank you for providing a fix this quickly!
I can confirm the font weight does not cause any issues anymore.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the bug report. You may give a good rating of the project at the CTAN page. Thank you.